# Lookup Fields based on Sales Team Roles

Tags: reporting, list, user, account-teams, case-teams

Do you know if possible to identify those in specific team roles via a lookup on an object?

Specifically, I would like to show what Team Role the user has that a record has been assigned to on a list view or report level.

On a list view level this does not seem possible so far. On reporting, this also seems only impossible out of the box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, no. When creating a lookup field, you get a dropdown of all objects you can select and the roles you've defined for your Account/Opportunity teams is not available for selection.

The reason for this is that [SalesTeamRole](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) is not an object itself. It's a standard picklist that is used on the junction objects between Account/Opportunity and User

In terms of *reports*, you could get what you want if you're talking about an object related to the teams (Account or Opportunity). You can use the *Account with Account Teams* report which displays all team members for a given account. Then, you can leverage [row-level formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_formulas_row_level_add.htm&type=0) to match which team member equals the owner of the given account to remove the other team members from the report.

1. Create a report using "Account with Account Teams"
2. Create a [Row-Level formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_formulas_row_level_add.htm&type=0) `IF(ACCOUNT_OWNER_NAME == MEMBER_NAME, "Same", "")`
3. Add a filter on the report using the row-level formula above so only team members who are the owner of the account show up
4. Add Team Role as a column

*This won't work with custom objects*. With that, you're left with doing custom automation on a custom field (text) to stamp the team role. Depending on your org/context, you could do a scheduled flow/apex or just use apex/record-triggered flows to run on insert and when the owner is updated.